# While Loop and Logical Operations

Tags: c++, while-loop, logical-operators

I want to use one AND operator and 2 OR operators combined in a While loop, but I am getting  an error in CPP.

```
while(vLessonNames.size>=1 && (log=='Y' || log=='y'))
```

I want to proceed when vector size is one or greater and log = Y or y

**Error: invalid use of member (did you forget the '&' ?)|**

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that .size might be a function. So try to rewrite the statement like:

```
while( ( (vLessonNames.size() >=1) && (log=='Y' || log=='y') ) )
{...}
```